# error in receiving serial data after sometime

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-port

My microcontroller continuously sends data in this format "900 899|900 898|900 800 900 700|900 799 900 756|". My Java code reads the data correctly for some time, but later it receives something like this " 900 899900 899".(note that there is a space before my first 900 which is causing error) causing "java.lang.NumberFormatException:" at the statement where i convert the string to int.. Please help me with this bug... 
Note: Check these readings "900 808 900 899|900 806 900 899| 900 899900 899|" It was supposed to read 900 804, instead it is reading the value received previously i.e 900 899

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

static int X[];
static int Y[];
InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[500];
byte[] noOfBalls = new byte[2];
byte[] temp = new byte[1];
static int arrayEnd = 0;

public SimpleRead(CommPortIdentifier portId) {

    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } 
    catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    }
    catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        arrayEnd = 0;
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 1 ) {
          /*    for(int i=0; i< 2; i++){
                    inputStream.read(temp);
                    noOfBalls[i] = temp[0];
                }
                String tmp = new String(noOfBalls);
                int iterations = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
                iterations = iterations * 2;
                for(int j =0; j< iterations; j++){*/
                inputStream.read(temp);
                if (temp[0] == '|') break;
                else
                    readBuffer[arrayEnd++] = temp[0];

                //}
           }
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        createXYArray();

       // serialPort.close();/****closing for now, later not needed*/
        break;
    }
}

private void createXYArray() {
    System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));
    X = new int[100];
    Y = new int[100];
    byte[] tmpXY = new byte[3];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < readBuffer.length){
        if(readBuffer[i]==0) break;
        int j=0;
        while(readBuffer[i]!=' ' && j!=3){
            //System.out.println(i);
            tmpXY[j] = readBuffer[i];
            //System.out.println("x "+tmpXY[j]);
            i++; j++;
        }
//  if(j!=3) break;
            createX(tmpXY);
        i++;
        j = 0;
        while(readBuffer[i]!=' ' && j!=3 ){
            tmpXY[j] = readBuffer[i];
        //  System.out.println("y "+tmpXY[j]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    /*  if(j==3){
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                three[k] = tmpXY[k];
            }
            createY(three);
        }
        else   */
            createY(tmpXY);
        i++;
    }
}

private static void createY(byte[] tmpY2) {

    String tmp = new String(tmpY2);
    Y[arrayEnd] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    //System.out.println(Y[arrayEnd]+" y");
    arrayEnd++;
}

private static void createX(byte[] tmpX2) {

    String tmp = new String(tmpX2);
    X[arrayEnd] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    //System.out.println(X[arrayEnd]+" x");

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the micro controller is sending the data you expect?

Comment: Yes i checked in puTTy, it was sending correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `trim` method on the `String` objects you're parsing. That will remove any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Yes that would help, but the real problem is with the reading.. Check this "900 808 900 899|900 806 900 899| 900 899900 899|" Here it was supposed to read 900 804. But instead of reading that, it is reading the value received previously. i.e 900 899. What could be wrong with my reader.?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i figured out what the error was. In the statement "while (inputStream.available() > 1 ) ", we have to replace 1 with -1. I dont really know why, but i did trial and error and i found it working properly for while (inputStream.available() > -1 ) .
If anyone knows why, please add in comments..